# Not able to find any element in appium for my mobile app

Tags: selenium, appium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng8Ty.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxznv.png)I am not able to find elements using any locators using appium in my mobile app, please check the attached screenshot  and my code below

```
driver.findElementById("serviceUrl").sendKeys("ABC");    
driver.findElementByClassName("android.widget.Button").click();
```

[image: Screenshot]

Appium server response

[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//*[@class='android.widget.EditText']","context":"","multiple":false}}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding '//*[@class='android.widget.EditText']' using 'XPATH' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding '//*[@class='android.widget.EditText']' using 'XPATH' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[debug] [MJSONWP] Matched JSONWP error code 7 to NoSuchElementError

Comment: How did you declare and initialize your driver?  Show code for that in your original post, please.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
driver.findElementById("serviceUrl").sendKeys("ABC");
```

Try this.

```
driver.findElementByClassName("android.widget.EditText").sendKeys("ABC");
```

As OP suggested you can try `xapth` as well.

```
driver.findElementByxpath("//*[@resource-id='serviceUrl']").sendKeys("ABC");
```

Or

```
driver.findElementByxpath("//*[@class='android.widget.EditText']").sendKeys("ABC");
```

Comment: Appritiate for quick response @Kajal , can you please add xpath also using resource id and class name that will best.

Comment: The first version will work if the driver is declared correctly.  If you want to use xpath, you have to specify resource-id in the xpath and not "id"  If you're using the correct driver, though, findElementById will attempt to search for ID, context-id, and resource-id (not necessarily in that order) but xpath is different.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i am still not able to find elements with above xpaths, please find driver declaration   File f= new File("src");
  File fs= new File(f,"LS_eCOA.apk");
  
  DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities();
  cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "EDC");
  cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, fs.getAbsolutePath());
  AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver=new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);

Comment: [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding '//*[@class='android.widget.EditText']' using 'XPATH' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[debug] [MJSONWP] Matched JSONWP error code 7 to NoSuchElementError

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("serviceUrl")).sendKeys("ABC");
```